Exportar PDF de sheets, guardar en drive y enviar por correo
No soy usuario avanzado y me estoy estrenando en esto. Agradezco su orientación para poder cumplir con mi objetivo, he revisado preguntas anteriores tratando de adaptar las respuestas a mis necesidades pero generalmente termina resultando en errores de "no se reconoce como una función" o "no está definido". Por eso recurro a ustedes para entender mejor a la vez que sigo estudiando. Quiero hacer algo en app Script en mi documento de sheets que consiste en:

Crear un directorio
Crear un PDF partiendo de una hoja de un libro
de sheets y guardarlo en el directorio creado en el paso 1
Enviar el pdf creado en el paso 2 por correo a una hora en especifico.

He logrado escribir la primera tarea exitosamente:
function crearCarpetasYEnviarPDFs() {
  var fecha = new Date();
  var year = fecha.getFullYear();
  var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
  var dia = fecha.getDate();

  // Crear carpeta raíz
  var nombreCarpetaRaiz = "Atenciones Pendientes con Proteínas 2024";
  var carpetaRaiz = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(nombreCarpetaRaiz);
  if (!carpetaRaiz.hasNext()) {
    carpetaRaiz = DriveApp.createFolder(nombreCarpetaRaiz);
  } else {
    carpetaRaiz = carpetaRaiz.next();
  }

  function obtenerNombreMes(numeroMes) {
  var nombresMeses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
  return nombresMeses[numeroMes - 1];
  // Crear carpeta de la fecha
  var nombreCarpetaFecha = dia + "-" + mes + "-" + year;
  var carpetaFecha = carpetaMes.getFoldersByName(nombreCarpetaFecha);
  if (!carpetaFecha.hasNext()) {
    carpetaFecha = carpetaMes.createFolder(nombreCarpetaFecha);
  } else {
    carpetaFecha = carpetaFecha.next();
  }
}

  // Crear carpeta del mes
  var nombreMes = obtenerNombreMes(mes);
  var nombreCarpetaMes = nombreMes;
  var carpetaMes = carpetaRaiz.getFoldersByName(nombreCarpetaMes);
  if (!carpetaMes.hasNext()) {
    carpetaMes = carpetaRaiz.createFolder(nombreCarpetaMes);
  } else {
    carpetaMes = carpetaMes.next();
  }

  // Crear carpeta de la fecha
  var nombreCarpetaFecha = dia + "-" + mes + "-" + year;
  var carpetaFecha = carpetaMes.getFoldersByName(nombreCarpetaFecha);
  if (!carpetaFecha.hasNext()) {
    carpetaFecha = carpetaMes.createFolder(nombreCarpetaFecha);
  } else {
    carpetaFecha = carpetaFecha.next();
  }
}

En el segundo paso, he logrado exportar directamente el pdf haciendo blob y dando algunas configuraciones de formato al archivo, sin embargo, este no se me guarda en Drive. No se si sea la mejor forma de hacerlo pero he usado otros códigos que le he pedido a copilot o gemini y siempre me dan algunos mas largos con blob y métodos como getAs y falla porque me dice que no reconoce getAs por lo que he visto que lo que mejor resulta es el export en la url. Aqui requiero ayuda para poder guardar este pdf en drive en carpetaFecha
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PWum5dXPKLzFcjHg23weku7sCfIo4q8aToMB8Xsb6ck/export?gid=766976778&format=pdf&portrait=false&size=letter&scale=2&gridlines=false&title=true

Por último, también requiero el apoyo en el código para poder enviar automáticamente este archivo pdf por correo a las 8:00 am a una dirección de correo especifica, he utilizado el siguiente código pero no he logrado que envíe el correo:
function reporteDiariodeProteinas() {
  var message = {
    to: "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", // Please set your email address.
    subject: "Reporte diario de proteinas"+fecha,
    body: "Le envio el reporte del dia de hoy. \n\nFeliz dia!.",
    attachments: [pdf] // entendiendo que pdf proviene de la solucion anterior
  };
  Logger.log("Message: " + JSON.stringify(message));
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

Agradezco en lo que me puedan guiar para obtener el mejor resultado

La pregunta debería ser más específica.
